# If statement inside If statement condition

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
int a, b;

if (a > 0)
{
    a--;
    DoSomething()
}
else if (b > 0)
{
    b--;
    DoSomething();
}
```

I heard it's better to not write the same line (`DoSomething();`) twice, so is there a way to do this:

```
int a, b;

if (a > 0 /* if true a--; */ || b > 0 /* if true b--; */)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

In other words, is there a better way to do this (without writing `DoSomething();` twice):

```
int a, b;

if (a > 0)
{
    a--;
    DoSomething()
}
else if (b > 0)
{
    b--;
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: You have to because in one you're doing `a--` and in the other `b--`.

Comment: @Haytam what's *inside* the `if` statement is irrelevant; the reason `DoSomething()` call has to be repeated is because the `else if` is also conditional. Had it been a catch-all `else` instead, it would be easy to refactor the code - just move the `DoSomething()` call outside the `if/else` statement, regardless of what's within the actual body of that statement.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the problem or the concerns you have, where you want to add another `if()` statement inside an `if()` statement condition and what it should do. Also explain what the concerns are in writing the method call twice. How should what action be performed depending on the possible values `a` and `b` have?

Comment: @CoolBots I only want to call ``DoSomething()`` if one of those conditions are true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the only or the last statements in the method, you could return in an additional else statement:

```cs
if (a > 0)
{
    a--;
}
else if (b > 0)
{
    b--;
}
else
{
    return;
} 
DoSomething();
```

If these are the last statements in a loop you can use `continue` instead of `return`. In a switch case you can use `break`.

---

If `DoSomething` involves something more complex, then using a flag would be appropriate. Otherwise calling `DoSomething` twice is just fine.

```cs
bool isDecremented = false;
if (a > 0)
{
    a--;
    isDecremented = true;
}
else if (b > 0)
{
    b--;
    isDecremented = true;
}

if (isDecremented)
{
    // Do something more complex.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a, b;

if (a > 0 || b > 0)
{
 if(a > 0)
    a--;
 else
   b--;

 DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: This is actually worse, due to the extra comparison

Answer (score -1):

You could use a local method to avoid the repetition:

```
void DecrementAndDoSomething(ref int i)
{
    i--;
    DoSomething();
}

if (a > 0) DecrementAndDoSomething(ref a);
else if (b > 0) DecrementAndDoSomething(ref b);
```

Comment: Did you mean `ref int`?

Comment: Also, aren't there now just 2 calls to a *different* function?

Comment: @CoolBots `ref` is correct, but the function is not different in each call.

Comment: `DecrementAndDoSomething(ref a)... `

Comment: I meant there's no improvement over OP's code - instead of two calls to `DoSomething()`, there are now 2 calls to a wrapper method.

Comment: @CoolBots But it consolidates use of the decrement operator. It also improves maintainability.

Answer (score -2):

How about writing like this?

```
            if ((a > 0 && a-- > 0) || (b > 0 && b-- > 0))
               DoSomething();
```

Comment: This is basically unmaintainable; the intent of the code is entirely unclear.